# What causes Excel action "List Rows present in a table" to fail to return existing Row?

Tags: power-automate

I need to filter out some data from an Excel table, but since the ID is not unique, I wanted to sort it by latest Submission Date from Ms. Forms.
Here's my List action

[image]

Before this step I also added a run script action to trigger table data refresh.
Now, the issue is, sometimes the filter works and it returns the correct existing data.
but it also sometimes fails, the List rows returns empty while in fact the Filter should find at least one data.

For the failed I have checked that the time between the new data inserted until the next similar data inputted is at least 1 day apart.
Is this a bug or do I have to do something so that the List rows action can run correctly all the time?

Comment: Try going to the List rows present in table action settings and turn on pagination.